# If statements in for loop don't work correctly - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement

```
for h=0:39
if h<10
    disp('primi 10')
elseif 10<=h<20
    disp('primi 20')        
elseif 20<=h<30
    disp('primi 30')
elseif 30<=h<40
    disp('primi 40')
end
end
```

The simple code above is the one that I've try to run in MATLAB, but as output I get something strange like:

```
primi 10
primi 10
primi 10
primi 10
primi 10
%first 10 senteces are corrected
...
primi 10
primi 20
primi 20
primi 20
.....
%until the end of the loop
```

So it seems that matlab doesn't exit from the

> elseif 10<=h<20
> disp('primi 20')

statement.
In fact the first 20 iterations are corrected, while the others no.
I really don't know how to correct it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should combine the “singular” conditions with logical operators, such as “elseif 10<=h && h<20”.
In your case, the compiler saw 10<=h first and resolved it as True and then proceeded to compare True<20, which is True as well, so everything was printed as 20.